# Which version of Rashi is learned on M'nachos chapters 7–10?

Tags: torah-study, rashi, nuschaot, talmud-bavli, maseches-menachos

Four chapters of *Bavli M'nachos* (chapters 7–10 in the *Bavli*'s order) have two versions of *Rashi* printed alongside in [the standard edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilna_Edition_Shas). Toward the top of the page is  *Rashi* printed in regular *Rashi* script. Toward the bottom is a commentary labeled "manuscript *Rashi*" and printed in smaller type. [At the beginning of the "manuscript *Rashi*" commentary](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=4533&size=2) is a note inserted by the publisher to the effect that the *Shita M'kubetzes* had said that the other commentary was not *Rashi* at all and had found a manuscript copy of the "manuscript *Rashi*" version.

Which version is typically/traditionally studied when learning those chapters?

Comment: I can't imagine anyone learning those chapters seriously and not learning both "Rashi"s and Tosfot and more. So your question seems to be limited to someone learning at a level of depth where only one "Rashi" is used.

Comment: @DoubleAA, one can learn for _iyun_ or _girsa_. Even someone learning for _iyun_ may, though he studies many commentaries, ignore one of the versions of _Rashi_, for all I know. Or maybe even people learning for _girsa_ learn both versions. I have no idea. Any such answer, posted below, preferably sourced (e.g. "this is how I was taught it by Rabbi X in _bes midrash_ Y"), would be most welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I learned Menachos by R Dovid Soloveitchick Shlita he would learn both Rashi's - the upper one he referred to as Rashi-in-der-hoich, and the other as Rashi csav-yad. I don't remember the specific order in which he learned them. If he learned both versions, you can be sure his father did too. In fact, the Gri"z stencil on Menachos does 'handel' with both Rashi's. It seems clear that the Rishonim had the csav-yad version, while the achronim had the upper Rashi. Both are good, of course; and both are important, because they were both used, each one in its own era. I personally had more gishmak in the csav-yad. Each person to their own taste.

Comment: Many thanks for your input. Welcome to Mi Yodeya! I hope you stick around and enjoy the site.

Answer (score 2):

Menachos is considered one of the hardest masechtos and in my opinion the hardest. Artscroll uses both editions continuously. Tosfos seems to have had only the MS edition which would mean it is more authentic. There aren't any other rishonim (except perhaps the rashbo) but there is a wealth of achronim at least fifty on the otsar hachochma. I would suggest using the yad binyomin by R Elyashiv which is very well written and is often brought in the artscroll.
The Mishne berura in likutai halachos does not seem to use the MS edition but the standard one so that should answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you would learn the one that is on the top in the Vilna Shas. The second Rashi, as you said, is רש״י כת״י, or רש״י כתב יד. The "Rashi K'tav Yad" means that it was found in a manuscript. However, for many years, the standard version was used, however different it was from the old manuscript. Therefore, I would advise on learning the first version, the one that appears closer to the top of the daf. If you want to learn more and use both girsaot, go ahead! It's great to learn any Torah. Hope this answer helps you.
P.S. With my chavruta, we are planning on using the standard, non-old-manuscript version.

Comment: Thanks, but my question was what is done typically or traditionally, not seeking advice. Your postscript is helpful, but isn't a large data set.